# "Сервисное обслуживание"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Это словосочетание можно увидеть сплошь и рядом. Но, по-моему, оно совершенно неграмотное — ведь это тавтология! Сервис — и есть обслуживание! "Обслуживательное обслуживание"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я, конечно, согласна, что в данное словосочетание - плеоназм. Но...Что такое сервис? Кроме того, что это обслуживание, это еще и сокращенное от "сервисный центр". И уже отсюда - сервисное обслуживание, т.е. обслуживание в сервисе (сервисном центре). Насколько это закрепится в языке? Поживем, увидим.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с Вами. Это тавтология. А может, плеоназм?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, это "масло масляное", но только - для "высоколобых" знатоков иностранных языков. По-русски же для многих требуется объяснение. Как пресловутый "прейскурант цен" или "памятный сувенир". Впрочем, с прейскурантом проблема, кажется, решилась с переходом на английский язык: прайс-лист "прайс-листом цен" никто не называет! Видимо, потому, что вторая часть слова понятна и по-русски.